# How do I replicate this C++ enum switch in Java?

Tags: java, c++, enums, switch-statement

I have some C++ code that looks like this:

```
enum {
     FOO = 0x01,
     BAR = 0x09;
};

switch (baz) {
     case FOO:
     {
          //...
     }
     break;
     case BAR:
     {
          //...
     }
     break;
}
```

Is it possible to replicate this behaviour in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Java has enums:

```
public enum BazEnum {
    FOO(0x01),
    BAR(0x09);

    private int value;

    BazEnum(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static BazEnum fromValue(int value) {
        for (BazEnum curenum : BazEnum.values()) {
            if (curenum.getValue() == value) {
                return curenum;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] params) {
        BazEnum baz = BazEnum.fromValue(0x09);

        switch baz {
            case FOO:
                ...
                break;
            case BAR:
                ...
                break;
            default:
                ...
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `BazEnum baz = BazEnum.fromValue(0x09); switch (baz)` was exactly whaty I needed - thanks!

Comment: @etheros: Just in case you didn't notice - it is a custom method defined in the BazEnum itself. By default enums have no properties in java.

Comment: Your `return null;` must be outside the `for` loop!

Comment: @Felix Dombek: Thanks for noticing, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Java Tutorial on Enum Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) which has examples on constructing enums and using them in switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just give the enum a name:

```
enum Baz
{
    FOO, BAR;
}
```

And then you can switch over expressions of type `Baz`:

```
    switch (baz)
    {
    case FOO:
        {

        }
        break;

    case BAR:
        {

        }
        break;
    }
```

You can still associate `FOO` and `BAR` with the values 1 and 9 if you want to:

```
enum Baz
{
    FOO(0x01), BAR(0x09);

    Baz(int value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public final int value;
}
```

Then you can say `baz.value` to get the associated value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Enum{
     FOO(0x01),
     BAR(0x09);

     Enum(int value){
         this.value=value;
     }
     private int value;
};

public void test() {
    Enum testEnum = null;
    switch(testEnum){
        case FOO:{}break;
        case BAR:{}break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While Java has enum's they are objects not primitives. It may be simpler to just use constants

```
static final int 
    FOO = 0x01,
    BAR = 0x09;

switch (baz) {
     case FOO:
          //...
          break;
     case BAR:
          //...
          break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just create an enum xDD

> ```
> public enum EnumName
> {
>   Foo(),Bar();
> } 
>
> switch (baz)
> {
>    case : EnumName.Foo
>     code
>     break;
> }
> ```